# Value passing in Struct Pointer

Tags: c++, c, struct

I've not worked in C, C++ from like 5-6 years.
But now I got to do a very small change (explained below).
I tried reading tutorials but only got confused.

Below I've struct containing 2 attributes.
I need to create its refrence and pass values to these 2 attributtes.

File in which struct is defined.

```
//List of includes
typedef struct dscvs {
UPD_TRC(trc_no);
UPD_STS(status);
}dscvs_i;
```

File in which struct variable is used
// Here I need to create a variable of type dscvs_i, so that I can feed the values inside UPD_TRC(trc_no) & UPD_STS(status);
// This is what I'm doing

```
dscvs_i *i_updsc;
i_updsc->trc_no = trcno;
```

But this is throwing error "error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue"

Please suggest.

Comment: Uhm, how about posting what UPD_TRC and UPD_STS does [edit your question!]

Comment: dont have access to that part of code

Comment: +1 same comment to say.

Comment: raul8: your compiler has access to it, so you have access as well.

Comment: And how on earth are WE supposed to tell you what to do?

Comment: C _or_ C++? While C++ accepts almost all C code, they are _vastly_ different languages and most good C idioms make very bad C++ idioms.

Comment: If `UPD_TRC` is a function that updates the trc, I'd suggest that you try `i_updsc->UPD_TRC(trcno);` Otherwise, you will want to ask for access to the source, or maybe even the documentation!

Comment: I'm guessing, since we can't see the code, that one of them macros have "const" in them.

Comment: @raul8: You do have access to that part of code. The definitions must be around for the compiler, so you can read them as well.

Comment: @raul8 i think UPD_TRC & UPD_STS are macro..

Comment: Is i_updsc just an uninicializer pointer? What type is trcno?

Answer (score 1):

Even if it compiled (which it seems to not do due to the macros wrapping the members in the structure), this:

```
dscvs_i *i_updsc;
i_updsc->trc_no = trcno;
```

is invalid code. You can't modify what the pointer `i_updsc` points at *before* allocating something, i.e. initializing the pointer to point at a valid piece of memory you can modify.

If you expect to have it around, you need to allocate dynamic memory using `malloc()`:

```
i_updsc = malloc(sizeof *i_updsc);
```

then check that the allocation succceeded, *before* trying to modify it:

```
if(i_updsc != NULL)
{
  i_updsc->trc_no = trcno;
}
```